# Python: how to convert a dictionary into a subscriptable array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I know how to convert a dictionary into an list in Python, but somehow when I try to get, say, the sum of the resulting list, I get the error `'dict_values' object is not subscriptable`. Also, I plan to sum only several items in the list.

```
dict = {A:1, B:2, C:3, D:4}
arr = dict.values()
the_sum = sum(arr[1:3])
```

Upon closer inspection, I noticed that when the resulting list is printed out, it always gives `dict_values(......)` as the output which I can't remove. How do I get around this?

Comment: Using `itertools.islice` as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72511573/19123103) gives a very fast way to slice the values and sum them.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

In python-3.X `dict.values` doesn't return a `list` object like how it used to perform in python-2.X. In python-3.x it returns a `dict-value` object which is a set-like object and uses a hash table for storing its items which is not suitable for indexing. This feature, in addition to supporting most of `set` attributes, is very optimized for operations like membership checking (using `in` operator).

If you want to get a list object, you need to convert it to list by passing the result to the `list()` function.

```
the_values = dict.values()
SUM = sum(list(the_values)[1:10])
```

Answer (score 11):

By assigning `dict.values()` to a list you are not converting it to a list; you are just storing it as dict_values (may be an object). To convert it write `value_list=list(dict.values())`. Now even while printing the `value_list` you will get the list elements and not `dict_values(......)`.

And as mentioned before don't use Python built-in names as your variable names; it may cause conflicts during execution and confusion while reading your code.

Answer (score 2):

Using `list(dictObj.values())` to wrap a `dict_values`object is not always successful, especially if the resulting `dict_values` list contains different data.

It will throw the Error:

```
{TypeError} 'generator' object is not callable
```

If you receive this error try to generate a iterable list using a [for comprehension](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/comprehensions-in-python/):

```
[x for x in dictObj.values()]
```

It will do the job

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it did appear like a list on the older Python questions asked here. But as @Kasramvd said, assuming you are using python 3.X, `dict.values` is a dictionary view object.
(Also, you definitely came up with this example hastily as you have four dictionary entries but want 10 list items, which is redundant.)

Answer (score 1):

Creating a new list using `list()` constructor, only to slice it is wasteful. Using `islice` from the built-in `itertools` module will be more efficient.

```py
from itertools import islice
dct = {'A':1, 'B':2, 'C':3, 'D':4}
arr = dct.values()
the_sum = sum(islice(arr, 1, 3))
the_sum
# 5
```

The difference is efficiency is noticeable especially if the dictionary is very large but the slice is small relative to it. For example, for a dictionary of 10mil key-value pairs, if you're slicing 20 pairs and summing their values, `islice` is ~39400x faster than constructing a list and slicing it.

```py
n = 10_000_000
dct = dict(zip(range(n), [0,1,2,3,4]*(n//5)))

%timeit sum(list(dct.values())[10:30])
# 120 ms ± 813 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit sum(islice(dct.values(), 10, 30))
# 3.04 µs ± 19.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Even if the slice is large, `islice` is still faster (though not as dramatic as a small slice)

```py
%timeit sum(list(dct.values())[1:n])
# 277 ms ± 2.24 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit sum(islice(dct.values(), 1, n))
# 181 ms ± 4.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

@mgilson is right. A dictionary , by its intrinsic nature, isn't ordered.

Still you can do this :

```
alpha = {"A":1,"B":2,"C":3,"D":4,"E":5}   # dictionary
my_list = []
for key,value in alpha.items() :
    my_list.append(value)
```

You can access your "values" from `my_list`, but it will not be in order.

Comment: Dictionary values are ordered in Python 3. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views says "Keys and values are iterated over in insertion order."