# Python 3 - how do I list the first 5 values from a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I load a dictionary-data from a JSON like this:

```
list_of_people = json.load(open('list_of_people.json'))
```

and I would like to pick the first 5 value items from this JSON. I tried to do it this way:

```
print(data.values()[0:5])
```

However, this resulted into

```
TypeError: 'dict_values' object is not subscriptable
```

How do I list that?

Comment: What do you mean by `first 5` .? First 5 in `data.values()` or first 5 from `data.values()` where `data.values()` needed to be in some order.?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: how to convert a dictionary into a subscriptable array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33674033/python-how-to-convert-a-dictionary-into-a-subscriptable-array)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just cast `values` to a list, like this:

```py
print(list(data.values())[0:5])
```

**NOTE:** if you are using Python 3.5 and earlier, dictionaries do NOT maintain order, in that case "the first 5 elements" is not really a thing...

if you have a specific way to sort them, you can use `sorted` to sort, and only then slice with `[0:5]`

Answer (score 1):

if you do not want to create an intermediate `list` of possibly many elements you could use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=islice#itertools.islice):

```
from itertools import islice

print(dict(islice(list_of_people.items(), 5)))   # shortened dict
print(list(islice(list_of_people.values(), 5)))  # shortened values
```

note that *first items of a dictionary* only makes sense from python 3.5 and later; before that dictionaries were unordered.

Comment: good point! if the dict is big casting values to list could be costly.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

```
import json
person = '{"name": "Bob", "languages": ["English", "Fench"], "location": "mumbai", "interests": "NLP"}'
person_dict = json.loads(person)
print(list(person_dict.values())[0:2])
```

output

```
 ['Bob', ['English', 'Fench']]
```