# TypeError: 'dict_values' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
best_params_train = dict(optimizer=optimizers[0], learning_rate=learning_rates[0],
                         cnn_train_type=cnn_train_types[0], 
                         cnn_arch=cnns_arch.values()[0],
                         dropout=dropouts[0])
```

it gives error at cnn_arch=cnns_arch.values()[0] as TypeError: 'dict_values' object is not subscriptable.
i tried converting into list but not worked.
how to convert the above dict(....) into list

```
exp_params_train = dict(optimizer=optimizers[1:], learning_rate=learning_rates[1:],
                        cnn_train_type=cnn_train_types[1:], dropout=dropouts[1:],
                        cnn_arch=cnns_arch.values())
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get: TypeError: 'dict\_values' object does not support indexing when using python 3.2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431638/get-typeerror-dict-values-object-does-not-support-indexing-when-using-python); Another one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33674033/python-how-to-convert-a-dictionary-into-a-subscriptable-array

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Quite on the contrary, it will work if you convert the `dict_values` object to a list:

```
cnn_arch=list(cnns_arch.values())[0]
```